# Flektierte Formen von Verben, die auf einem Kürzel bauen

Tags: verb, abbreviation

Wie schreibt man die verschiedenen flektierten Formen von Verben, die aus einem (nominalen) Kürzel ausgehen? Die möglichen Varianten unten sehen alle holprig aus, die Sätze zu sagen scheint mir aber einfacher:

> Ich SMSe dir.
>   Wenn du mir es SMS-st, habe ich es schriftlich.
>   Die Straße habe ich schon ge-pe-es-t.
>   GPS:e mir sofort dein Lokal!

Oder sind Umschreibungen immer vorzuziehen?

> Ich schicke dir ein SMS.

statt

> Ich SMSe dir.

Kürzel, die als Normalwörter aufgefasst werden können, wie z.B. „LASER“ sind ja weit einfacher, finde ich:

> Ich habe die ekelhafte Warze an der Nase weglasern lassen.

Comment: Die Straße habe ich schon _globales Standortbestimmungssystemst_. _Globales Standortbestimmungssysteme_ mir sofort dein Lokal!  :) Ich verstehe nicht ganz, was du überhaupt mit GPS als Verb aussagen willst. Wäre nicht etwas wie "schick mir den Standort von dem Lokal" einfacher? Meiner Meinungs nach ergibt GPS als Verb, in deinen Beispielen, wenig Sinn...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es gibt drei Arten von Abkürzungen:

Akronyme, das sind Wörter, die zwar aus einer Abkürzung entstanden sind, die man aber wie ein normales Wort ausspricht:

- Laser
- NATO
- Aids
- BAföG
- Azubi
- TÜV

Diese Akronyme kann man übrigens weiter in Initialworte (Wörter, bei denen jeder Buchstabe der Anfangsbuchstabe eines anderen Wortes ist, z.B. »Laser« aus »**L**ight **A**mplification by **S**timulated **E**mission of **R**adiation«) und Silbenkurzworte unterteilen, wobei letztere aus den Silben anderer Wörter bestehen (»Kripo« = »**Kri**minal**po**lizei«).

Dann gibt es Abkürzungen, bei denen man die Buchstaben einzeln ausspricht:

- PKW (gesprochen »pekaweh«)
- CD (»tsedee«)
- SMS (»essemess«)
- ARD (»aaerdee«)
- GmbH (»geembehaa«)
- StVO (»essteefauoh«)

und es gibt Abkürzungen, bei denen man das Wort bzw. den Begriff ausspricht, der abgekürzt wurde:

- Dr. (gesprochen »Doktor«)
- z.B. (»zum Beispiel«)
- i.d.R. (»in der Regel«)
- usw. (»und so weiter«)
- ges.gesch. (»gesetzlich geschützt«)

---

Da es sich bei der ersten Gruppe (den Akronymen) eigentlich um ganz normale Nomen handelt, kann man sie - falls Bedarf besteht, wie andere Nomen auch desubstantivieren:

- Laser - weglasern (»Lisa hat sich ein Tattoo weglasern lassen.«)
- NATO - natoisieren (»Staat X hat Angst davor, dass seine Nachbarn weiter natoisiert werden.«)
  <sub>*(Wobei es sicherlich unterschiedliche Auffassungen darüber gibt, ob die Schreibweise »natoisieren« der Schreibweise »NATOisieren« vorzuziehen ist.)*</sub>

Bei der letzten Gruppe ist es auch einfach, man schreibt das Wort einfach aus und desubstantiviert es dann:

- Dr. - herumdoktern (»Warum lässt du diesen Stümper daran herumdoktern?«)

Schwierig ist aber die zweite Gruppe. Hier gibt es eigentlich keinen vernünftigen Weg.

Im Fall von *SMS* hat sich das Verb *simsen* etabliert, aber zumindest in Österreich hört man auch oft *essemessen*, wofür es aber keine allgemein etablierte Schreibweise gibt (gesehen habe ich »SMSen«, »SMSn« und »smsen«). Das lässt sich aber nicht ohne weiters auf andere Abkürzungen übertragen.

Im Fall von GPS (das ja wie »tschie-pi-ess« und nicht wie »ge-pe-ess« ausgesprochen wird) wird man ein Verb vermutlich als *»tschiepiessen«* aussprechen, aber wohl kaum so schreiben.

Comment: Ich würde aber sagen, dass das *Herumdoktern* nicht von der Abkürzung *Dr.* kommt sondern vom ganzen Wort (*Doktor*), das ja - siehe *Onkel Doktor* / *Ich gehe zum Doktor* - umgangsprachlich für den Arzt verwendet wird.

Answer (score 3):

Im Deutschen sind ja seit einigen Jahren alle Hemmungen zur Großschreibung – selbst im Wort – gefallen. Eigentlich ist nur wichtig, dass die Abkürzung erkennbar bleibt. Also die Endungen einfach nur dranklatschen.

> Die Straße habe ich schon GPSt.

Wobei ich allerdings nicht wüsste, was genau das nun heißen soll. In's Navi eingegeben? In OpenStreetMap eingetragen? Wahrscheinlich gibt's deshalb auch noch kein eingedeutschtes Verb davon.

Die SMS ist hingegen kein gutes Beispiel, denn das zugehörige Verb heißt *simsen*.

> Ich simse dir. Wenn du es mir simst, habe ich es schriftlich.

Comment: Im Perfekt müsste es doch aber »gegpst« heißen?

Comment: Es heißt ja auch nicht *gerasiert*.

Comment: Wenn es ja das Wort "simsen" für SMS gibt, könnte man für "ein PM schicken" (private message in einem Internetforum schicken) "pimmen" oder sogar "pimsen" sagen??

Comment: Es gibt das Verb *piëmmen*.

Comment: Muss man das genau so schreiben, mit dem Trema, oder geht es auch ohne?

Comment: Ich vermute, die meisten Leute schreiben es *PMmen*.